# Terminating a scala program?

Tags: scala, hadoop2

I have used try catch as part of my mapreduce code. I am reducing my values based on COUNT in the below code. how do i terminate the job using the code in the below

```
class RepReducer extends Reducer[NullWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable] {
  override def reduce(key: NullWritable, values: Iterable[Text], context: Reducer[NullWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable]#Context): Unit = {
    val count = values.toList.length
    if (count == 0){
      try {
        context.write(new Text("Number of tables with less than 40% coverage"), new IntWritable(count))
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          Console.err.println(" ")
          e.printStackTrace()
      }
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("terminate job") //here i want to terminate if count is not equal to 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `sys.exit()` 
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.package@exit(status:Int):Nothing

Comment: `sys.exit()`, while technically the answer to the question, is rarely the right behavior. Perhaps in Hadoop it is, but I think we need more details to figure out if this is an XY problem or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you still need to call context.write to return the control back to Hadoop even if you decide to skip certain data in the 'else'.